# Unpickling problem in python under apache (mod_python)

Tags: python, apache, pickle

I'm writing a web application that talks over network socket to a server that I develop in python. To simplify things I decided to pack the data into a class and transfer it after pickling.

To test the concept I've written a code that pickles the class and unpickles it but it doesn't work. Same code runs in python interpreter. Below is the code and the error I get:

```
class testClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.blah       = 'bleh'
        self.meaning    = 42
        self.isComplete = False

    def dumpy(self):
        print self.blah
        print self.meaning
        print self.isComplete

def index():
    foo   = testClass()
    p_foo = pickle.dumps(foo)

    foo = pickle.loads(p_foo)

    foo.dumpy()
```

This is the error:

> ImportError: No module named
>   _mp_11b334e84556201b42d59ca560e0f6ad
>
> MODULE CACHE DETAILS
>
> Accessed:       Fri May 20 16:23:51
>   2011 Generation:     0
>
> _mp_11b334e84556201b42d59ca560e0f6ad {
>   FileName: '/var/www/stormstation-web/sea_monitor/management_client.py'
>   Instance:     1 [IMPORT]
>   Generation:   1
>   Modified:     Fri May 20 16:23:47 2011
>   Imported:     Fri May 20 16:23:51 2011
>   }

Comment: "Pickle" and "Web Service"? Don't forget that everyone who can send pickled data to your script can **execute arbitrary python code** on the system unpickling it. If that's a problem for you better go with something like JSON.

Comment: No it's not a service and it's not that complicated to require JSON and/or more advanced things (and whole thing will run on a intranet, not internet). I also have some neat security measures on my mind.

Comment: Do **not** use mod_python, seriously. It's broken beyond repair, unmaintained, and a huge pain in any imaginable way. Use mod_wsgi. Oh, and really, reconsider the usage of pickling for such a use case. Not only is it a security nightmare (and no "neat security measures" will help you there, sorry), you also have portability problems, e.g. if the client uses a different Python version than what you have on the server.

Comment: OK. Since pickling is not working as I expected, usage of python on the web side is not a must now. I'll use something else and will not implement it in python. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the case.

You cannot easily use pickled classes, functions or class instances with mod_python.

This document describes the problem from the point of view of Sessions, but still applies to your usage:
http://www.dscpl.com.au/wiki/ModPython/Articles/IssuesWithSessionObjects

Basic problem:

> The source of the problems and limitations is how the operation of the "pickle" serialisation routine is affected by the module reloading mechanism implemented by mod_python. That is, the module loading mechanism as underlies the Python*Handler directives and as implemented by the apache.import_module() function. The particular types of data which are known to be affected are function objects and class objects.

Summarising:

> In order to ensure that no strange problems at all are likely to occur, it is suggested that only basic builtin Python types, ie., scalars, tuples, lists and dictionaries, be stored in session objects. That is, avoid any type of object which has user defined code associated with it.

Comment: Ah, OK. That's the kind of a document I was trying to find. Thanks.